# ChildView didn't maintain its ParentView Frame

Tags: objective-c

Hope all of you will be fine. Guys i have a situation, I have a uiview and uibutton as under:

```html
UIView* containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, self.view.frame.size.width, 70)];
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(SettingPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings_button.png"];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted & UIControlStateNormal & UIControlStateSelected];
    
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 40, 40);
    button.center = containerView.center;
    [containerView addSubview:button];
```

The problem is uibutton appear far from uiview instead of in the middle of uiview. What i am mistaking, please guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: Also can any body please tell me what is the difference between self.view.bounds.size.width and self.view.frame.size.width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you change a view's `center` property the `frame` property will be changed automatically so you only should set the button center:

```
button.center = CGPointMake(containerView.frame.size.width  / 2, 
                              containerView.frame.size.height / 2);
```

Now, whenever you change the center property you need to manually tell the view to redraw itself using  `setNeedsDisplay` :

```
[button setNeedsDisplay]
```

and lastly, the difference between frame and bounds that frame defines the position and size relative to the parent view while bounds describes the drawing area inside (or outside) the frame.